# Spring-Integration Webflux exception handling

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

If an exception occurs in a spring-integration webflux flow, the exception itself (with stacktrace) is sent back to the caller as payload through MessagePublishingErrorHandler, which uses an error channel from the "errorChannel" header, not the default error channel.

How can I set up an error handler similar to [WebExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux-error-handling)? I want to produce an Http status code and possibly a `DefaultErrorAttributes` object as response.

Simply defining a flow that starts from the `errorChannel` doesn't work, the error message won't end up there. I tried to define my own `fluxErrorChannel`, but it appears that it is also not used as error channel, the errors do not end up in my `errorFlow`:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fooRestFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            WebFlux.inboundGateway("/foo")
                    .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
                    .requestPayloadType(Map.class)
                    .errorChannel(fluxErrorChannel()))
            .channel(bazFlow().getInputChannel())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel fluxErrorChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.flux().get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(fluxErrorChannel())
            .transform(source -> source)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow bazFlow() {
    return f -> f.split(Map.class, map -> map.get("items"))
            .channel(MessageChannels.flux())
            .<String>handle((p, h) -> throw new RuntimeException())
            .aggregate();
}
```

**UPDATE**

In `MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceiveMessageReactive` my error channel defined on the WebFlux.inboundGateway is never used to set the error channel, rather the error channel is always the `replyChannel` which is being created [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/2df71fba3046aa0e259eb14a53fbd22cccc1cafa/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/gateway/MessagingGatewaySupport.java#L597):

```
FutureReplyChannel replyChannel = new FutureReplyChannel();

Message<?> requestMessage = MutableMessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
    .setReplyChannel(replyChannel)
    .setHeader(this.messagingTemplate.getSendTimeoutHeader(), null)
    .setHeader(this.messagingTemplate.getReceiveTimeoutHeader(), null)
    .setErrorChannel(replyChannel)
    .build();
```

The error channel is ultimately being reset to the `originalErrorChannelHandler` in `Mono.fromFuture`, but that error channel is ˋnullˋ in my case. Also, the `onErrorResume` lambda is never invoked:

```
return Mono.fromFuture(replyChannel.messageFuture)
    .doOnSubscribe(s -> {
        if (!error && this.countsEnabled) {
            this.messageCount.incrementAndGet();
        }
    })
    .<Message<?>>map(replyMessage ->
        MessageBuilder.fromMessage(replyMessage)
            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, originalReplyChannelHeader)
            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, originalErrorChannelHeader)
            .build())
    .onErrorResume(t -> error ? Mono.error(t) : handleSendError(requestMessage, t));
```

How is this intended to work?

Comment: relevant part of the reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-default-reply-channel

Comment: In the error handling section of the reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler WebFlux errors are not mentioned - are they different from sync/async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug; the `ErrorMessage` created for the exception by the error handler is sent to the `errorChannel` header (which has to be the `replyChannel` so the gateway gets the result). The gateway should then invoke the error flow (if present) and return the result of that.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4541

Comment: great :o) Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: 5.0.9 should be released on Monday.